# sklearn:ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1297, 2145]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)

for train, test in kfold.split(X, y):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=12, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
    model.fit(X[train], y[train], epochs=10, verbose=1)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

r2_score(y[test], y_pred.round())
```

> ValueError on the last line: Found input variables with inconsistent
>   numbers of samples: [1297, 2145]

Comment: What am I missing in the last code?

Comment: How is X_test defined? (and why is that line at the beginning of your code?)

Comment: X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)   (That line was for the reference to what I was defining y_pred)

Comment: You are evalulating using the X from one of the folds with predictions of a different train/test split, no wonder they are of different size. The code is just wrong, make sure to use the same kind of split to evaluate.